# linq/ef: How to form the query which connects multiple tables to return result?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api

I'm extremely new to ASP .NET and LINQ so please forgive me for my ignorance.

I've a Region class:

```
public class Region
    {
        [Key]
        public int Region_ID { get; set; }
        public string Region_Name { get; set; }

    }
```

And a Service class:

```
public class Service
    {
        [Key]
        public int Service_ID { get; set; }
        public string Service_Name { get; set; }
    }
```

And a mapping class which stores the many-many mapping of service_IDs with region_IDs:

```
public class Mapping_ServiceToRegion
    {
        [Key]
        public int Service_ID { get; set; }
        public int Region_ID { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I want to create an API function which outputs Region_Name based on given Service_ID. This is what I have so far in my RegionsController:

```
// GET api/Regions/Service_ID
    [ResponseType(typeof(Region))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetRegion(int id)
    {

        var region_id = from sr in db.Mapping_ServiceToRegions
                           where sr.Service_ID == id
                           select sr.Region_ID;

        var region = await db.Regions.Select(r =>
            new Region()
            {
                Region_ID = r.Region_ID,
                Region_Name = r.Region_Name
            }).SingleOrDefaultAsync(r => r.Region_ID == region_id); //ERROR

        if (region == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(region);
    }
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Cannot convert lambda expression because it is not a delegate type.

I realize that my **region_id** variable will have multiple region_ids based on a service_id. How can I modify the code to account for this? Is there an IN operator that I can use to say r.Region_ID IN region_id?

And does the above code look correct otherwise?

Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't edit your post like that ... you actually asking two question in same post. your current edit doesn't reflect original question and thus may invalidate the posted answer if I exclude my edited answer. STOP doing that

Comment: Sorry - I figured it would be easier for you/others to follow through what's going on instead of having to create multiple Edit sections. I will reedit it back to the original. Many apologies.

Comment: That's alright ... NO it's OK to edit your post but append the new edit and don't overwrite the original post.

Comment: Gotcha! Btw, "SingleOrDefaultAsync" wasn't working so I used "FirstOrDefaultAsync" instead but its returning only 1 result even when there are multiple in the SQL output. What function should I be using?

Comment: don't get wrong but you shouldn't ask multiple question in same post. That's not acceptable. You already have asked two questions. Create a separate post and link this post if you want.

Comment: @Rahul Thanks! just posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38287545/how-to-use-async-and-await-in-linq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the `SingleOrDefaultAsync()` call using `Contains()` method like below since your `region_id` is of `IEnumerable<T>` and not a single value and so you can't perform direct equality comparison.

```
SingleOrDefaultAsync(r => region_id.Contains(r.Region_ID))
```

Ahh!!! here `Region` is one of EF mapped entity and you are trying to construct that and thus the error. You should either chose to select an `Anonymous` type (or) use a custom viewmodel/DTO object like

```
    var region = await db.Regions.Select(r =>
        new
        {
            Region_ID = r.Region_ID,
            Region_Name = r.Region_Name
        }).SingleOrDefaultAsync(r => region_id.Contains(r.Region_ID));
```

Comment: It's building successfully now but I'm getting an exception:

The entity or complex type 'x.Models.Region' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Is my code above incorrectly constructed?

Comment: @90abyss, not sure since can't see `x.Models.Region` from your posted code. Moreover, looks like that's a separate question which should be posted separately.

Comment: its referring to the Region class above. When I debug, "var region = await......" line is where it gives exception.

Comment: @90abyss, what if you run without debugging? if you are debugging then disable `just my code`

Comment: Then I'm getting that error in my browser when i type /api/regions/1: "Models.Region' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.".. I think that "var region = ...." line is not correct somehow.