# How to use async and await in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-web-api

I'm new to ASP.NET and was trying to work on a sample project. I know this is a silly qs but please bear with me. My code below is returning only one result even when there are multiple rows returned in the SQL query. I realize that FirstOrDefaultAsync returns only the first element. I was going through the documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.queryableextensions(v=vs.113).aspx but I couldn't find what to use instead of FirstOrDefaultAsync that would return not just the first row but everything that matches my SQL condition.

This is my code so far:

```
    [ResponseType(typeof(Region))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetRegion(int id)
    {

        var region_id = from sr in db.ServiceToRegions
                           where sr.Service_ID == id
                           select sr.Region_ID;

        var region = await db.Regions.Select(r =>
            new 
            {
                Region_ID = r.Region_ID,
                Region_Name = r.Region_Name
            }).FirstOrDefaultAsync(r => region_id.Contains(r.Region_ID)); //QQQ

        if (region == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(region);
    }
```

What should I be using instead of FirstOrDefaultAsync?

Comment: Try .Select (...) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use ToListAsync() after Where:

```
var region = await db.Regions
    .Select(r =>
        new Region
        {
            Region_ID = r.Region_ID,
            Region_Name = r.Region_Name
        }
    )
    .Where(r => region_id.Contains(r.Region_ID))
    .ToListAsync();
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220257(v=vs.113).aspx

Note "new Region" to solve your anonymous type problem for serialization (I cannot comment on Scott's answer).

**UDPATE**

Because you try to partially load a model (only 2 properties), you need to use a ViewModel like this:

```
public class RegionVM
{
    public int Region_ID { get; set; }
    public string Region_Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then change your code for this:

```
var region = await db.Regions
    .Select(r =>
        new RegionVM
        {
            Region_ID = r.Region_ID,
            Region_Name = r.Region_Name
        }
    )
    .Where(r => region_id.Contains(r.Region_ID))
    .ToListAsync();
```

Don't forget to update your response type!

Comment: getting another exception if I do that: The entity or complex type 'x.Models.Region' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query

Comment: try using a DTO, I forgot you cannot project in an entity that is part of your model.

Comment: Yeah, DTO works. Thanks! So will I have to continue creating DTOs for such cases? There is no other alternative?

Comment: if you are doing a service layer, you may be interested by WEB API 2 with OData v4. You can protect and return partial model without using DTO/VM as json. It depends if you're making a web site or a data service.

Comment: [Here is a tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint) on what Sproulx is talking about, I also would reccomend this approach.

Comment: Thanks so much! You guys are magnificent! I'll certainly read more on that.

Comment: If you want to look forward and learn new web technologies, I recommend you to read about AngularJS to query (easily!) your data service built with webapi 2 and odata. These 3 technologies just work so well together.

Comment: Hey @Sproulx - thanks for your comment. I surely will! Please do tell me any good learning resources/tutorials that you know of that combines all 3 above.

Comment: Scott Chamberlain's tutorial is a good starting point for OData and Web Api. Then, I read [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/806029/Getting-started-with-AngularJS-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Par) to learn how to mix mvc and AngularJS (and learn the basic of AngularJS). After that, you'll be able to mix OData/Web Api with AngularJS. For a real application (not only to learn), I highly recommend to split Front End Application and Data Service in two distinct Visual Studio Solution. Its easier to scale in this way.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the `FirstOrDefaultAsync` with a combination of a `Where` and a `ToListAsync()`

```
var region = await db.Regions.Select(r =>
        new 
        {
            Region_ID = r.Region_ID,
            Region_Name = r.Region_Name
        }).Where(r => region_id.Contains(r.Region_ID)).ToListAsync();
```

This will return a `List<someAnnonamousType>`.

Comment: Getting an exception now: Type '<>f__AnonymousType3`2[System.Int32,System.String]' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.  If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute.  See the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other supported types.

Comment: I am not the most familiar with ASP.NET, I don't know the "correct" way to fix it, but if I was writing it I would just not use an anonymous class anymore and use a real class in the `new` that has the proper annotations to make it serializable applied.

Comment: When I do a: "var region = await ...Select(r =>
                        new Region()
                        {
                            ...
                        })...."


Then I get this exception: The entity or complex type 'x.Models.Region' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Comment: Try putting the where before the select. Also, is `Region` the same `Region` as is being used for `db.Regions`? When I said "use a real class" I ment make a new DTO class to assign to, not to reuse the existing entity. See [Sproulx's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38287593/80274) for a full example of what I was talking about.

Answer (score 0):

In that case you want all records, you should remove the call to `FirstOrDefaultAsync()` which will return you `IEnumerable<anonymoustype>` like below. You can include the condition using `Where()` LINQ extension method

```
    var region = await db.Regions                      
                  .Select(r =>
                      new 
                       {
                         Region_ID = r.Region_ID,
                         Region_Name = r.Region_Name
                       }).Where(r => region_id.Contains(r.Region_ID));
```

Comment: You can't await the code anymore, you don't have anything that retuns an awaitable object now.

Comment: @Rahul As Scott pointed out, I'm getting this error: "Cannot await System.Linq.IQueryable"